# How to correctly set windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds in XF5?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx

We've been upgrading our application to Xamarin.Forms 5 and it's unclear how to correctly set the AppCompat theme now that we've migrated to the AndroidX package. When using

```xml
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarAppCompat" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

I get `error APT2260: resource android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar not found.`

If I remove the `android:` the application compiles, but the navigation bar overlaps controls on the page.

Comment: Another possibility: is it possible some other theme setting makes this one irrelevant?

Comment: We couldn't see other code, but if it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: We haven't been able to repro with new applications and our application is too large to slice things out. This is just the latest effort, though we've been through other workarounds and such (hiding the action bar altogether prevents overlap there, but scrollviews still don't account for the size difference of the blank space reserved for the action bar when the soft keyboard displays so it overlaps fields (though it does scroll, just not quite enough to account for the software based action bars; everything works fine when the device has physical buttons instead of soft actions)

Comment: Besides a repro, could you maybe just provide guidance on how to correctly use the new AppCompat package to set these theme styles? It's unclear what's different from the old AppCompat packages in terms of application

Comment: Does it work if you change the parent theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` ?

Comment: not sure what that might entail for the rest of our style; it's an older app in maintenance and is built on Holo

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see the full code of your `styles.xml`, but I tried to create a simple  xamarin android app with the latest vertion of nuget `Xamarin.Androidx.AppCompat`.

The default code of file `styles.xml` is:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Note：You can compare it to your code. If the problem still exists after correction, you can post the code of your `styles.xml` here.

Comment: Is it possible that Xamarin is no longer fully compatible with the Holo theme?

Comment: Have you tried to change your code to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` ?

Comment: There appear to be a number of non-trivial compatibility issues between Holo and MaterialComponents and I didn't write this theme so that seems like it would require a more significant effort than the stakeholder is looking for at the moment. Maybe as a longer term improvement, but this is just a bug that has started happening on newer devices with different soft input behaviors than were previously present when the app was originally written.